# Можно ли при вставке заменять NULL'ы на значения по умолчанию?

Tags: sql-server

Можно задать Default, но если будет явная вставка NULL'а, то это не сработает.

Есть какие-то еще варианты, кроме триггера?

Comment: Например, убрать явную вставку NULL'а?

Comment: это должно решаться на уровне софта, а не на уровне СУБД. Если хотите решение SQL-запрос, то можно вложить isnull в insert. Типа `insert into tabl1 values( isnull(@a,1))`

Comment: А чем плох триггер?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да хотелось бы минимальными телодвижениями это решить. Т.е у меня висит уникальный индекс на одно поле и я не хочу, что бы при вставке появилось 2 записи с NULL и Пусто. Т.е нужно при вставке подменять значения.

Comment: Это поле уникальное? Тогда default не пойдет. А тип у него какой? Нельзя ли sequence сделать?

Comment: Текст. Нужно именно NULL на пустую строку подменить, что бы если бы это привело к повторяющемуся значению в Индексе, то запись не вставилась.

Comment: Ну тогда просто сделать `ALTER TABLE ... NOT NULL` на это поле?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, можно, но в таком случае нужно менять коды программ, а я хотел малой кровью корректировать их данные.

Comment: Считаю что явная вставка NULL это какая-то неправильная ситуация, попросите разрабочика приложения обернуть (isnull(@val,0)) это значение и назовите ему желаемый DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

Явная вставка NULL не нужна и не имеет смысла. Замените ее тем значением, которое надо вставить:

```
insert into tab1 values (isnull(@col1, defaultValue))
```